# Text Evolution Program Will Not Run

Tags: python, syntax-error, nameerror

I downloaded a python program recently to see how exactly it works. It was a simple evolution of text program where you enter some text and it outputs random text/number/symbols until in evolves into the text you entered. The program was already created to work, which is the problem, it doesn't, and I'm uncertain why. Here is the program:

```
    #-----------------------------------------------------
    # Python 'Evolution of Text' Program
    # More programs at: usingpython.com/programs
    #-----------------------------------------------------

    import string
    import random
    import time


    possibleCharacters = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits + string.ascii_uppercase + ' .,!?;:'

    target = input("Enter your target text: ")
    attemptThis = ''.join(random.choice(possibleCharacters) for i in range(len(target)))   
    attemptNext = ''

    completed = False

    generation = 0

    while completed == False:
        print(attemptThis)
        attemptNext = ''
        completed = True
        for i in range(len(target)):
           if attemptThis[i] != target[i]:
                completed = False
                attemptNext += random.choice(possibleCharacters)
           else:
                attemptNext += target[i]
        generation += 1
        attemptThis = attemptNext
        time.sleep(0.1)

    print("Target matched! That took " + str(generation) + " generation(s)")
```

So, I ran the program a few times in Python Canopy and these are the errors it gave me:

```
    Welcome to Canopy's interactive data-analysis environment!
    with pylab-backend set to: qt
    Type '?' for more information.

    In [1]: %run "c:\users\phillip\appdata\local\temp\tmpxe9get.py"

    Enter your target text: Hellow World!
      File "<string>", line 1
        Hellow World!
                   ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax


    In [2]: %run "c:\users\phillip\appdata\local\temp\tmpvj64ac.py"

    Enter your target text: HellowWorld
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    c:\users\phillip\appdata\local\temp\tmpvj64ac.py in <module>()
         10 possibleCharacters = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits + string.ascii_uppercase + ' .,!?;:'
         11 
    ---> 12 target = input("Enter your target text: ")
         13 attemptThis = ''.join(random.choice(possibleCharacters) for i in range(len(target)))
         14 attemptNext = ''

    C:\Users\Phillip\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy- 1.5.1.2730.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\zmq\ipkernel.pyc in <lambda>(prompt)
        362         if content.get('allow_stdin', False):
        363             raw_input = lambda prompt='': self._raw_input(prompt, ident, parent)
    --> 364             input = lambda prompt='': eval(raw_input(prompt))
        365         else:
        366             raw_input = input = lambda prompt='' : self._no_raw_input()

    C:\Users\Phillip\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy 1.5.1.2730.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\kernel\zmq\ipkernel.pyc in <module>()

    NameError: name 'HellowWorld' is not defined 

    In [3]: %run "c:\users\phillip\appdata\local\temp\tmpulqoxo.py"

    Enter your target text: What is wrong with this stupid program?
      File "<string>", line 1
        What is wrong with this stupid program?
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm uncertain if I'm simply entering my text incorrectly or if it's an issue with the program itself. It throws invalid syntax at random letters (lowercase it seems) when words are spaced. When entering a single letter or word or group of words with no spacing it throws a name error as though it is trying to define the entered text. I really don't understand the errors, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My psychic powers are telling me you are using Python 2.x and this script was written in Python 3.x.

Comment: And that you should therefore use `raw_input` not `input`...

Comment: To specify what's happening, input() in Python 2 will read in a line, and run it as Python code. "Hellow World!" is not valid Python.

Comment: Ah, yes, your psychic powers were indeed correct. And I feel stupid now. But hey, live and learn.

Answer (score 0):

It is raw_input instead of input